# how do I solve the problem of bind enum in spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

when I use common param to do some common logic by using spring. I found I can`t use enum for input. like postman or other.

Comment: In order to get the right answer you actually need to ask a question.

Comment: What you posted looks like a question-answer in the question. Edit your question to move the answer part in a answer.

Comment: thanks.I have been moved.   @davidxxx

Comment: @Forest10. Great,  This very well explained. You have my vote.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem,I try lots of ways. finally,thanks god.I success.

This is only for RequestMethod.POST.And your param must be object (maybe RequestMethod.GET or single param also available.but I haven`t found how to do that )

#### example

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CommonParam implements Serializable {

    /**
     *

     */
    @Size(min = 1, max = CommonConstants.MAX_PARTITION_SIZE)
    private List<String> texts;

    /**
     * 
     */
    @NotNull
    private KeyTypeEnum keyTypeEnum;
}
```

```
@PostMapping("/do")
public RpcResult do(@RequestBody @Valid CommonParam commonParam) {
   .....
}
```

#### the last but not the least

```
public enum KeyTypeEnum {

    /**
     * 手机号
     */
    PHONE(1, "phone");

    private int value;
    private String desc;

    KeyTypeEnum(int value, String desc) {
        this.value = value;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public static KeyTypeEnum getByDesc(String desc) {
        for (KeyTypeEnum b : KeyTypeEnum.values()) {
            if (b.getDesc()
                .equals(desc)) {
                return b;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static KeyTypeEnum getByValue(int value) {
        for (KeyTypeEnum b : KeyTypeEnum.values()) {
            if (Objects.equals(b.getValue(), value)) {
                return b;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

}
```

By Using `@JsonCreator` we can ensure the input like '1'(this code is the KeyTypeEnum`s already defined value) can be success convert to enum.
`@JsonValue` ensure '1' can be success get for spring.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The value of KeyTypeEnum should be `PHONE` in the JSON payload. It's not feasible to uniquely resolve by the value `1` as you are expecting. You can have multiple enum with the same value.

Comment: the param name has been qualify which enum should convert.I try ```PHONE```,but failed. can you show some example code?Thanks!